# Remove hyphen in breadcrumbs

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

I use breadcrumbs on my website but would like to display the path name without the hyphen sign.
Can someone help me out here? Thanks.

Example: 
From

```
Home / cambodja-informatie / algemeen / geografie
```

To

```
Home / cambodja informatie / algemeen / geografie
```

My breadcrumb structure:

```
<?php
if($location = substr(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), 1))
$dirlist = explode('/', $location);
else
$dirlist = array();

$count = array_push($dirlist, basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));

$address = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

echo '<a href="'.$address.'">Home</a>';

for($i = 0; $i < ($count-1); $i++)
echo '&nbsp;/&nbsp;<a href="'.($address .= '/'.$dirlist[$i]).'">'.$dirlist[$i].'</a>';
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to make logical rules for what and when to replace. Based on the info you provide now, this would simply suffice:

```
str_replace('-', ' ', $dirlist[$i])
```

However, what if you're referring to, in Dutch as that is your site's language, `EHBO-cursus`? That would end up as a grammatically wrong `EHBO cursus`. Actually you're already doing that right now, `cambodja informatie` is already wrong and should remain `cambodja-informatie`, see [here](http://woordenlijst.org/leidraad/6/7/) and [here](https://onzetaal.nl/taaladvies/advies/klinkerbotsing).

The problem isn't as trivial as your suggested solution makes it seem. For cases like this, you need to distinguish between the [**slug**, ie. the standardized systematic name to be used in URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_URL#Slug), and the **title**, which is used as a display string. Your current solution isn't going to cut it in many scenarios.

Comment: Good explanation - note, missing a `;` at end of line.

Comment: @Dan intentional, it's meant to replace the second `.$dirlist[$i].` in the concatenation on the last line.

Comment: Thanks for your clear explanation. As for now, it works out for me!

Answer (score 0):

```
strtr($dirlist[$i], '-', ' ');
```

Comment: How about some explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following variable:

```
$name = str_replace("-", " ", $dirlist[$i]);
```

and call it like so

```
echo '&nbsp;/&nbsp;<a href="'.($address .= '/'.$dirlist[$i]).'">'.$name.'</a>';
```

Your actually calling the directorylist as the name, which is why there is a hyphen. The str_replace just finds it and replaces it with the space.